# SwiftUI: NavigationLink's Destination initialized whenever its parent is redrawn

Tags: swiftui, combine, navigationlink

So I have a `ParentView`, which has a `NavigationLink`, leading to a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`-conforming `PageViewController`.

Now that `ParentView` also has some subscription on some publisher. Whenever that one is fired, not only will the `ParentView` redraw all its content (which it should), it will also re-initialize the (already presenting) `PageViewController`.

That leads to stuttering/glitching, because the `PageViewController` is already presenting and using the controllers that are continually being resetted.

Below is the `ParentView` and  `PageViewController` (without the Coordinator stuff), both is pretty vanilla. The commented guard line is a hack I tried to prevent it from updating if displayed already. It helps but it's still stuttering on every swipe.

So the question is: How can we prevent the updating of a presented ViewController-wrapped-View when its presenting View is redrawn?

```
struct ParentView: View {

    @Binding var something: Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: PageViewController(controllers: controllers)) {
            Text("Push me")
        }
    }
}
```

```
final class PageViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var controllers: [UIViewController]
    private var currentPage = 0

    init(controllers: [UIViewController]) {
        self.controllers = controllers
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
        let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
            transitionStyle: .scroll,
            navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
        pageViewController.dataSource = context.coordinator
        pageViewController.delegate = context.coordinator

        return pageViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
        // I tried this: guard pageViewController.viewControllers!.isEmpty else { return }
        pageViewController.setViewControllers(
            [controllers[currentPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that PageViewController should be a struct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, forgot to mention that, but tried that too, to no avail.

Comment: SwiftUI doesn't redraw so much as reread. body is a pretty normal computed property that is read when necessary. I don't think that there is a silver bullet for your problem, each case is different. If your update is caused by an ObservedObject then you can delay the objectWillChange.send() until a better time but you need to take control of the sending to do that.

Comment: Well it calls `init()` on the `PageViewController`, that at least resets the `controllers`, which are already presented. I think I found a solution: Even though the `PageViewController` is reinitialized, it's coordinator is not. So to store the controllers (and the current page) on the coordinator keeps it from being interrupted. And the best: In `updateUIViewController` you can access both properties via `context.coordinator`. This is significantly different than Apple's implementation in their PageView Tutorial, from which my code was taken, but I think that's the way it should be.

Comment: The controllers are hosted Views though and they should be stable or at least I guess that they are hosted Views as this is for SwiftUI. I agree that calling init() is not a particularly good idea but I wouldn't have thought it would be a catastrophe.

Comment: I just looked at your code again and I noticed that you use a local property for currentPage. When I did the same thing I used a binding which means that it is preserved between instancations although I did it that way to communicate with the parent View and the UIPageControl.

Answer (score 1):

If your controllers don't change after being displayed once, you can simply call:

```
pageViewController.setViewControllers([controllers[currentPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true)
```

from the `makeUIViewController(context:)` function instead of the `updateUIViewController(:)` function.